# UIView in UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5, uiactionsheet

I m adding a `UIView` in  `UIActionSheet` and I need to add four labels on the view and a close button.But I need the UIactionSheet to start from center of screen.When I m adhusting the dimensions I couldnot get it .

```
-(IBAction)buttontapped:(id)sender{


     UIView    *showDetailsView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10, 320, 260)];

        showDetailsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UILabel  *name =[[UILabel alloc] init];
        [name setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40,250, 50)];
        name.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        name.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        name .font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:12];
        name.text=@"Name";
        [showDetailsView addSubview:name];


        UIActionSheet *aac = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil  otherButtonTitles:@"Close", nil];
        aac.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleAutomatic;
        [aac addSubview:showDetailsView];
        [aac setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,400)];
        [aac showInView:self.view];

}
```

I can see it added from the bottom but it is not expanding to the center of screen like in the following figure:I need to increase its height.

Comment: Hi for taking the screen shot of the particular window use shift + command + 4 and then space then click the desired window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
[aac setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320,400)];
```

Comment: I have used it .But no luck

Comment: What can I modify further ?

Comment: Just comment this line [aac addSubview:showDetailsView]; and see what result it gives.

Comment: I got only UIactionsheet but I need to add UIView to it because I want to display some labels in it .

Comment: @Sindhia     
        [aac showInView:self.view]; [aac setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320,400)];

Comment: Now I m getting like in the figure I addded to my code.But can I show any separation between UIView and UIactionsheet.My aac is of height 600 and IUView in it is of height 400.But I caouldnot see the view ended separation after 400 in UIactionsheet.How is it possible.And I couldalso not see the close button of UIactionsheet .

Answer (score 1):

From one of the SO's answer I get this method and it's works like charm :)

```
-(void)setActionSheetHeight
{
    CGRect actionSheetRect = self.myActionSheet.frame;
    CGFloat orgHeight = actionSheetRect.size.height;
    actionSheetRect.origin.y -= 214; //height of picker
    actionSheetRect.size.height = orgHeight+214;
    self.myActionSheet.frame = actionSheetRect;

    [self.myPicker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];

    CGRect pickerRect = self.myPicker.frame;
    pickerRect.origin.y = orgHeight;
    self.myPicker.frame = pickerRect;
}
```

Here `myActionSheet` is one `UIActionSheet` iVar.
Here `myPicker` is one `UIPickerView` iVar.
Instead of `214` static value you can set your desired value and according to that it will set the height of the `UIActionSheet`.

**NOTE**
Must be called after the action sheet is shown ie after the `[self.myActionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];` kind of line of code. Means after call the `show` method on action sheet.

Answer (score 0):

UIActionSheet is designed to be presented from the bottom of the screen.

You can display it in center on ipad only..not in iphone.

You can use custom Alertview for your requirement.

https://github.com/alokard/BlockAlertView

Comment: Actually no matter if it starts from bottom of screen ,but it not getting expanded to the center.My UIActionsheet is just to the bottom of the screen

Comment: You can use showFromRect: method while displaying action sheet if you want it somewhere other than bottom.  [actionSheet showFromRect:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 10) inView:placeholderview animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

When you present the actionsheet, you need to send appropriate message to present it. Refer to

[showFromRect:inView:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActionSheet/showFromRect%3ainView%3aanimated%3a)

[showInView:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActionSheet/showInView%3a)

For showInView:, you can have an invisible view with the bottom at mid-height of the view controller and top aligned to the top of viewcontroller.

For showFromRect:inView:animated:, if you have any UIView to which the actionsheet needs to be anchored, you can used it there.